# Change target controller/action from middleware

Tags: php, laravel

I have two resources `/test` and `/blabla`.
For the `/test` I have registered middleware. In the middleware, based on certain condition,  I would like to *redirect* current call to the controller/action which serve `/blabla` resource, transparently for user (no any extra client request, no 302 status response code etc..). How can I achieve it ?

Comment: Would it make sense to catch the exception in the routes file and then you can take a different route for each case?

Comment: @ajon it's not what I want to achieve. I like an idea with making changes in `routes.php` just need to clarify some questions (see bellow)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like your solution might be better suited in the routes file.  You are suggesting serving a different route given a certain condition.

So in your routes.php file:

```
Route::get('test', function(){
   if($condition){
       return App::make('App\Http\Controllers\TestController')->index();
   } else {
       return App::make('App\Http\Controllers\BlaBlaController')->index();
   }
});
```

If you still want to handle it in the middleware you should be able to do the same thing as above:

```
return App::make($controller)->index(); // or whatever controller method you want to call.
```

If you need both sets of middlewares to be called, then inside the constructor (after calling your middlewares) check your condition and call the other controller like above.

Comment: I like your idea with routes.php, but if I'll call `App::make` does it mean that Middlewares will be skipped ?

Comment: call `App::make` essentially calls the constructor which is where the middlewares are called.  The middlewares are not skipped on the controllers that are called using `App:make`.

Comment: Seems in Lumen it works differently (I mentioned Laravel in the topic, cause I thought they are the same). Anyway, thanks for an idea!

Comment: always return: Class does not exist (calling controller Class)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the users url, I don't think there's any way other than returning a redirect. Most users don't notice the redirect so it will probably seem "transparent."

In that case, your middleware function looks like:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (something == thingy) {
        return redirect('/blabla');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: @j-t-grimes this is the point, I don't want to change the url that user will see it. I want to serve the same url with help another pair controller/action (based on extra http header, for instance)